# Why do I get the error "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) in my code", but it still works if I add a unrelated print statement?

Tags: c, string, struct, memory-leaks, io

I am still new to C, so I have no idea what might be happening here.

In this implementation of a `String` struct which should behave in a object-oriented way, there seems to be some error in the `set` function as I get this diagnostic:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

This is my .h file:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct String_Struct
{
    char* value;
    unsigned int length;

    void (*set) (struct String_Struct* self, char* value);
    bool (*equals) (const struct String_Struct* self, const struct String_Struct* other);
    int (*compareTo) (const struct String_Struct* self, const struct String_Struct* other);
    void (*concat) (struct String_Struct* self, const struct String_Struct* other);
    void (*freeString) (struct String_Struct* self);
} String;

String* newString (char* value);
void set (String* self, char* value);
bool equals (const String* self, const String* other);
int compareTo (const String* self, const String* other);
void concat (String* self, const String* other);
void freeString (String* self);
```

This is its implementation:

```
#include "mystring.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void set (String* self, char* value)
{
    // Only proceed if self and value exist
    if (!self || !value)
    {
        return;
    }

    free(self->value);
    self->length = strlen(value) + 1;
    self->value = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * self->length);
    strcpy(self->value, value);
}

int compareTo (const String* self, const String* other)
{
    if ((!self && other) || (self && !other))
        return INT_MIN;

    return strcmp(self->value, other->value);
}

bool equals (const String* self, const String* other)
{
    if ((!self && other) || (self && !other))
        return false;

    if (self == other)
        return true;

    return strcmp(self->value, other->value) == 0;
}

void concat (String* self, const String* other)
{
    if (!self || !other)
    {
        return;
    }

    char* result = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(self->value) + strlen(other->value) + 2));

    strcpy(result, self->value);
    strcat(result, other->value);

    self->set(self, result);
}

void freeString (String* self)
{
    free(self->value);
    free(self);
}

String* newString (char* value)
{
    String* str = (String*) malloc(sizeof(String));

    str->set = &set;
    str->equals = &equals;
    str->compareTo = &compareTo;
    str->concat = &concat;
    str->freeString = &freeString;

    str->set(str, value);

    return str;
}
```

And this is my main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mystring.h"

int main()
{
    String* string = newString("Hello");

    printf("%s", string->value);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the error which I provided above. But when I add a unrelated printf statement in "set" like so:

```
void set (String* self, char* value)
{
    // Only proceed if self and value exist
    if (!self || !value)
    {
        return;
    }

    printf("Debug");

    free(self->value);
    self->length = strlen(value) + 1;
    self->value = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * self->length);
    strcpy(self->value, value);
}
```

This is the console output:
DebugHello
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: `newString (char* value)` calls `set()` whose first action is to call `free()` on `...->value`. Sadly, because `malloc()` doesn't initialise the allocated block, `value` contains garbage that is passed to `free()`... Solution: use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`... Me? I'd drop this and do other things... C is not an object oriented language. Kludges like this only make code more bloated and convoluted... There's no provision for a 'destructor' so there's bound to be memory leaks...

Comment: @Fe2O3 *Sadly, because malloc() doesn't initialise the allocated block, value contains garbage that is passed to free()...* Uh? The content of the allocated memory has nothing to do this the address management of it.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès the content of the allocated memory is passed to `free` when `free(self->value);` is called in `set` function. It is not about `self` but about `value` pointer inside`

Comment: Oh I see, forgive me (was focused on `set` function). Problem is in `newString` where `value` must be set to `NULL`.

Comment: @Anton - More about *"C is not an object oriented language"* Calling through function pointers in the struct will give you an additional indirection compared to C++. And the `std::string` contains additional optimizations, like not reallocate the buffer in `set` if it is already long enough. Most people using C do that because they don't want OOP. You seem to be undecided.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least a problem in the `set` function:

```
  free(self->value);                 //  you free a pointer that has 
  self->length = strlen(value) + 1;  //  never been initialized
```

Freeing pointer that has never been initialized doesn't make sense and it results in undefined behaviour (most of the time some kind of crash).

You should initialize that pointer to NULL in `newString`:

```
  ...
  str->freeString = &freeString;
  str->value = NULL;  // <<< add this

  str->set(str, value);
  ...
```

With that modification your code seems to work. I didn't investigate any further, so there might be more problems (bugs and/or design errors) elsewhere in this code.

Comment: @Fe2O3 that doesn't seem necessary, but `calloc` is definitely an option here. But anyway the whole thing looks more or less like one big design error with a huge probability of getting memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

OP title: "*... but it still works if I add a unrelated print statement?*" and "*Can anyone explain why?*"

`printf()` uses dynamic memory allocation for its functionality.

Introducing that "*(unrelated) print statement*" changes the environment (possibly being the first time dynamic allocation has been used during execution.) As such, whatever bytes the not-working version of your program was accessing are either replaced or redirected to other bytes that contain enough NUL characters to be interpreted as `free(NULL)`, a perfectly legitimate parameter to the function.

Lesson: When allocating variables (especially `struct`'s), either *on the stack* or *from the heap*, be sure to initialise the variables completely. It may seem wasteful, but this practice will save you hours of chasing elusive bugs in misbehaving programs (and posting questions on SO).

Further: `malloc()` can fail. Get in the habit of writing code that checks the return value from calls like this. Presuming everything works all of the time is called "*whistling in the dark.*"